# When form is submitted, validate html checkbox and display javascript alert if it is not checked

Tags: jquery, wordpress, validation, contact-form-7

I'm trying to validate a form in HTML using jQuery and possibly jQuery validation plugin. What I want to happen is when the submit button is pressed, it should validate whether a certain HTML checkbox is checked or not. If it is not checked, I want to give out a javascript alert error saying that it is not checked. Otherwise the form should submit normally. I'm trying to integrate this into a WordPress form created by using the Contact Form 7 plugin.

I have added my code as per request.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 

    <script> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm" action="action.php" method="post"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="tos" value="Agreed to TOS" id="confirm">
<input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Don't have much, yet and I was trying to use jquery validate. It might be simple by using just javascript.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: in contact form 7 there is option to validate checkbox is required or not. You just need to select require checkbox while creating form element.

Comment: I have updated with the code. Just the HTML check box needs to be validated.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
<input id="submit" type ="submit" name ="submit" />
```

is your submit button in form, add `onclick` to it.

```
<input id="submit" type ="submit" name ="submit" oncLick = "return validate();">
```

Your validate should look like:

```
function validate(){
  if your checkbox is set
       return true;
  else
       return false;
}
```

If your `validate` function returns true, then only your form will be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

```
var atleast = 1;
function validate() {
    debugger;
    var CHK = document.getElementById("<%=chk1");
    var checkbox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
        if (checkbox[i].checked) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (atleast > counter) {
        alert("Please select atleast " + atleast + " employee ");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

//give

```
enter code here
```

For DEMO

http://design.ionxindia.com/Manager/AttendanceRequest

Comment: Your demo isn't working, it shows a login screen. Also, it's better to demonstrate it with a Stack Snippet.